# Batch file for finding top N files which are not of a perticular type

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I want some basic help with Windows commands to automate some of my work.

I have a folder in which I get some files, I need to run a fix process in order to correct the file contents.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a "n=0, limit=3"
>"testfile1.txt" (
 for /f %%F in ('dir /o-d /b *_SourceFile_*.csv') do (

        set %x= echo %%F |findstr /i/v "\.fixed.csv" 
    if %x% not nul
    (
            FixFileWithWinFormat.exe %%F
            2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
    )

  )
)
:break
echo 'competed'
```

This bit of code above if I comment out the %x is working the if condition is not making it to work. Don't know why. It could be silly.

Comment: Read `set /?` and `if /?` and [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
    set %x= echo %%F |findstr /i/v "\.fixed.csv" 
if %x% not nul
```

These two lines are incorrect. It's better to state what the code is intended to do, otherwise we're guessing.

The `set` statement can't be used to set an environment variable in that manner - it's very simple, `set var=string` and `%x` is an invalid variable to set.

The `not nul` idea can be accomplished by `if not defined x` - but no `%`s.

So - assuming you wish to execute the following parenthesised statement-sequence if the filename in `%%f` is not found in the file, then

```
findstr /i "%%f" ".\fixed.csv" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (your statementsequence in parentheses)
```

should do the task. I'm not sure of the filename `fixed.csv` here. `\.fixed.csv` will locate a filename `.fixed.csv` in the root directory, whereas `.\fixed.csv` will locate a file `fixed.csv` in the current directory (and hence the `.\` is redundant.)

`findstr` will find the string contained in `%%f` in the file, with `/i` making the seach case-insensitive. `>nul` redirects any output to *nowhere*. `errorlevel` is set to `0` if the text is found, non-zero otherwise.

`if errorlevel 1` means "if *errorlevel* is 1 or greater". Note that `if errorlevel 0` means "if *errorlevel* is 0 or greater" (ie. always, for all intents and purposes) hence to detect *errorlevel* 0 (ie "text found" you need `if not errorlevel 1`)

**and** the opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`

(not sure about your terminating condition; seems to be attempting to force a divide-by-zero after *limit* iterations. Don't have the time to test atm - soz)

Comment: Script wont work. random errors. and putting pushd \\networkshare\somedrive\someshare

Comment: @echo off
pushd \\somenetworkdrive\project\DEV\FEEDS\UnixFiles
setlocal
rem set the count of files which you want to fix for.
set /a "n=0, limit=3"
rem log what we are doing
rem take the latest 3 files /o-d will give date desc and look for the csvfile
>"whathappened.log" (for /f %%F in ('dir /o-d /b *_filename_*.csv') do (
    
    rem call the fixer executable which fixes the file.
    FixFileWithWinFormat.exe %%F
    rem increment the variable if 3 then go to break;
    2>nul set /a "n+=1, 1/(limit-n)"||goto :break
  )
)
:break
popd